# C comparing two char arrays in a multidimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

How would I efficiently compare two rows of a multidimensional array?

for example if i have the following multidimensional array:

```
char Multi_Array[4][5] = {
                            {0,1,2,3,4}, //Row1
                            {5,6,7,8,9}, //Row2
                            {0,1,2,3,4}, //Row3
                            {5,9,6,3,2}  //Row4
                         }
```

I would like the compare each row with each other to eventually get all the unique rows

Comment: There is a standard function to [compare arbitrary memory](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcmp), maybe you can use it?

Comment: I'm done answering really basic stuff that would take you 5 minutes to find in a beginner-level C programming book.

Comment: Works perfectly Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the most efficient is probably brute-force or hard-coded logic.

For larger arrays, you might choose to make a separate array of pointers to the first character in each row, and then run `qsort` along with `memcmp`.

After sorting the pointers, you can then traverse that sorted array and use `memcmp` again to compare a row with its previous.  You can remove duplicates from the list at the same time.  *e.g.*

```
int i, uniq = 0;
for( i = 1; i < NUM_ROWS; i++ )
{
    if( 0 != memcmp( sorted[uniq], sorted[i], ROW_SIZE ) )
        sorted[++uniq] = sorted[i];
}
++uniq;
```

If your rows are small, you may choose to skip the array of pointers completely and modify the array in-place (if that's what you want to do).

Comment: @user3095420 If you have got your answer please accept the answer for better clarity. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers to know more.